# detecting year in list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of strings like this:

```
words = ['hello', 'world', 'name', '1', '2018']
```

I looking for the fastest way (python 3.6) to detect year "word" in the list. For example, "2018" is year. "1" not. Let's define the acceptable year range to 2000-2020.

### Possible solution

Check if the word is number (`'2018'.isdigit()`) and then convert it to int and check if valid range.

What is the fastest way to do it in python?

Comment: since the year range is not that big maybe the direct string comparison would be better. As in `next((x for x in words if any(x == pos for pos in {str(c) for c in range(2000, 2020+1)})), None)`

Comment: or `years = [x for x in s if x.isdigit() and 2000 <= int(x) <= 2020]`. "fastest" needs benching.

Comment: or `years = [y for y in words if y.isdigit() and int(y) in range(2000,2020)]`

Comment: You can also use the `datetime.strptime('2018', '%Y')` for a larger range, but it has higher computational cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a set of your valid years (as strings). Then loop through each of the words you want to test to check if it is a valid year:

```
words = ['hello', 'world', 'name', '1', '2018']
valid_years = {str(x) for x in range(2000,2021)}

for word in words:
    if word in valid_years:
        print word
```

As Martijn Pieters mentioned in the comments, sets are the fastest solution for accessing items with an O(1) complexity:

> Sets let you test for membership in O(1) time, using a list has a linear O(length_of_list) cost

---

**EDIT**:

As you can see in the comments, there are a lot of different ways of generating the set of `valid_years`, as long as your data structure is a **Set** you will have the fastest way of doing what you want.

You can read more here:

- [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [Sets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_sets.htm)
- [Complexities for different Python data structures](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) *(so you can understand which data structures in Python are quicker for specific operations)*

Comment: You'd want to make that a *set* instead, at which point you have an unbeatably fast solution. Use `valid_years = {str(x) for x in range(2000, 2021)}` (and avoid the `+ 1`). Sets let you test for membership in O(1) time, using a list has a linear O(length_of_list) cost.

Comment: Well thought @MartijnPieters , sets are extremely for accessing items in them!

Comment: Alternative syntax: `set(map(str, range(2000,2021)))`, but that's just preference.

Answer (score -2):

Concatenate list to one string with special split char. Use regex to search.

For example:

```
word_tmp = " ".join(words)
re.search("\b20[0-2]\d\b", word_tmp)
```

Comment: this also matches everything up to `"2029"`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, you are right. But I won't waste more time on regex string... OP can do it himself.

Comment: I don't think we have responsibility to do everything for OP. Especially this is very easy to implement(For example, change to `\b20([0-1]\d|20)\b`). And as OP has even more gold badges than me, I absolutely confirm that he just need a hint.